# How to filter with extra column in JSON PHP

Tags: php, sql, json

I have a little statistic page where I can summorize my txt messages by user and by country. 
I need now to have a new column where i can have operator as well.
To be more accurate, I need column to count all the Vodafone messages. I have already operator in my database and there are 5 different operators. I just need to bring out Vodafone.
Here are json php:

```
require_once("../corporate/php/modules/core/init.inc.php");

$where = " queue.dt_entered >= '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["startdate"]))." 00:00:00' and queue.dt_entered <= '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["enddate"]))." 23:59:59' ";

$result = $db -> query("    
    SELECT queue.user_id AS user, users.username as username, SUM( queue.amount ) AS amount, COUNT( queue.amount ) AS count, IFNULL( (

    SELECT TRIM( country ) 
    FROM CORE_E164
    WHERE code = SUBSTR( queue.receiver, 3, 3 ) ) , IFNULL( (

    SELECT TRIM( country ) 
    FROM CORE_E164
    WHERE code = SUBSTR( queue.receiver, 3, 2 ) ) , IFNULL( (

    SELECT TRIM( country ) 
    FROM CORE_E164
    WHERE code = SUBSTR( queue.receiver, 3, 1 ) ) ,  'None'
    )
    )
    ) AS country
    FROM sms_queue AS queue, users AS users
    WHERE queue.user_id = users.id
    AND queue.client_type =  'corporative'
    AND ".$where."
    GROUP BY user, country      
    order by username
");

$result_array = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($result_array, array("user" => $row["user"],
                                                                    "username" => $row["username"],
                                                                    "country" => $row["country"],
                                                                    "amount" => $row["amount"],
                                                                    "count" => $row["count"]
                                                                    ));
}

$result_total = array(
    "success"=>true,
    "messages" => $result_array
);

echo json_encode($result_total);
```

I am adding now the html page as well:

```
function columnWrap(val){
    return '<div style="white-space:normal !important;">'+ val +'</div>';
}

var stat_store=new Ext.data.JsonStore({         
    root: 'messages',
  fields : [
        {name: 'id', mapping: 'user'},
        {name: 'username', mapping: 'username'},
        {name: 'country', mapping: 'country'},
        {name: 'amount', mapping: 'amount'},
        {name: 'count', mapping: 'count'},
        {name: 'emt', mapping: 'emt'}
    ],
  proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url:'group_stats.json.php'})
});

var filters = new Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters({
    encode: false,
    local: true,
    filters: [{
        type: 'string',
        dataIndex: 'username'
    },{
        type: 'string',
        dataIndex: 'country'
    },{
        type: 'string',
        dataIndex: 'operator'
    }]
});    

var summary = new Ext.ux.grid.GridSummary();

var stat_grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    store: stat_store,
    region: 'center',
    plugins: [filters, summary],
    columns: [
            {header: "User ID", width: 50, dataIndex: 'id', sortable: true},
            {header: "Username", width: 160, dataIndex: 'username', sortable: true, filterable: true},
            {header: "Target country", width: 330, dataIndex: 'country', sortable: true, filterable: true},
            {header: "Request count", width: 110, dataIndex: 'count', sortable: true, filterable: true, summaryType: 'sum'},
            {header: "EMT count", width: 110, dataIndex: 'count', sortable: true, filterable: true, summaryType: 'sum'},
            {header: "SMS sum", width: 110, dataIndex: 'amount', sortable: true, filterable: true, summaryType: 'sum'}
    ]
});

var FilterPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
    labelAlign: 'top',
    frame:true,
    region: 'north',
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
    height: 95,
    items: [{
        layout:'column',
        items:[{
            columnWidth: 0.1,
            layout: 'form',
            items: [new Ext.form.DateField({
                    fieldLabel: 'Alguskuupäev',
                    name: 'startdate',
                    id: 'startdate',
                    value: new Date().format('Y-m-d'),
                    format:'Y-m-d',
                    anchor:'95%',
                    allowBlank:false })]
        },{
            columnWidth:.1,
            layout: 'form',
            items: [ new Ext.form.DateField({
                    fieldLabel: 'Lõppkuupäev',
                    name: 'enddate',
                    id: 'enddate',
                    value: new Date().format('Y-m-d'),
                    format:'Y-m-d',
                    anchor:'95%',
                    allowBlank:false })]
        }]
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Otsi',
        handler: function(){
            stat_store.baseParams = {startdate: Ext.get('startdate').dom.value, enddate: Ext.get('enddate').dom.value};
            stat_store.load({params:{startdate: Ext.get('startdate').dom.value, enddate: Ext.get('enddate').dom.value}});
        }
    }]      
});

var ContentPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    layout: 'border',
    items : [FilterPanel, stat_grid],
    renderTo: 'list',
width: Ext.get('contentdiv').getWidth() - 5,
height: Ext.get('contentdiv').getHeight() - 30
});
```

Thank you,
Allan

Comment: Where's the problem? Why don't You just add the new column to the table and use it in the query?

Comment: Can you help me how to do that, so rest of columns will be accurate as well? How to filter out, that on that extra column "operator" I will see only vodafone sum of messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So You want to count number of Vodafone messages among all selected messages.

```
SELECT ... SUM(IF(queue.operator = 'Vodafone', 1, 0)) AS vodafoners FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If You have access to some administration of the database ([Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/), [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) or something similar), You can add the column in it. If You don't have such access, use SQL query to add the column:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD columnName columnType
```

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE sms_queue ADD opername VARCHAR(50)
```

And then use that column in Your SQL query:

```
... WHERE sms_queue.opername = 'Vodafone'
```

I also suggest using an index on that column.

Comment: I have in database name operator. There are 5 different operators. I just need to bring out Vodafone.

Comment: Then use just the second half of my answer :-)

Comment: I need to see amount of all the messages and then extra column with only vodafone. How can I do that?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sms_queue WHERE <name-of-your-operator-column> = 'Vodafone'

Comment: My query here, how should I add it: SELECT queue.user_id AS user, users.username as username, SUM(queue.amount) AS amount, COUNT(queue.amount) AS count, IFNULL((SELECT TRIM(country) FROM CORE_E164 WHERE code = SUBSTR( queue.receiver,3,3)), IFNULL((SELECT TRIM(country) FROM CORE_E164 WHERE code = SUBSTR(queue.receiver,3,2)), IFNULL((SELECT TRIM(country) FROM CORE_E164 WHERE code = SUBSTR(queue.receiver,3,1)), 'None'))) AS country FROM sms_queue AS queue, users AS users WHERE queue.user_id = users.id AND queue.client_type = 'corporative' AND ".$where." GROUP BY user, country order by username");

Comment: What is the name of the operator column? Put it in Your query in the WHERE clause: ... `WHERE queue.<your-column-name> = 'Vodafone' AND queue.user_id =` ... If You need to use SQL, learn it's basics!

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood the question. You need new column in Your _result_! My apologies :-)

Comment: My apologies for insulting You, again. See the second answer, is it what You needed?